# Spark Dataframe groupBy With agg(collect_set(...)) Produces Lowercase Structure Member Name

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

With Spark 1.6 (CDH 5.9.2) ... note this code:

```
println("r1:")
r1.show(20,false)
r1.printSchema()

val r2 = r1.groupBy('cid, 'leadR).agg(collect_set('follower) as "followRz")

println("r2:")
r2.show(20,false)
r2.printSchema()
```

Which uses this case class (for `r1` middle & last column):

```
case class UuidWrapper(
                      id : java.lang.String,
                      lastSeenDate : java.lang.Long,
                      firstSeenDate : java.lang.Long
                    )
```

Intending to get this case class's schema with differing column names (for the entire `r2`):

```
case class UuidRelationships(
                            clientId : java.lang.Long,
                            leader : UuidWrapper,
                            followers : Array[UuidWrapper]
                          )
```

The preceding code produces the following output:

```
r1:
+---+------------+-----------+
|cid|leadR       |follower   |
+---+------------+-----------+
|5  |[55,555,555]|[2,555,555]|
|5  |[55,555,555]|[3,555,555]|
|7  |[66,777,777]|[5,777,777]|
|7  |[66,777,777]|[6,777,777]|
+---+------------+-----------+

root
 |-- cid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- leadR: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastSeenDate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstSeenDate: long (nullable = true)
 |-- follower: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastSeenDate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstSeenDate: long (nullable = true)

r2:
+---+------------+--------------------------+
|cid|leadR       |followRz                  |
+---+------------+--------------------------+
|7  |[66,777,777]|[[5,777,777], [6,777,777]]|
|5  |[55,555,555]|[[2,555,555], [3,555,555]]|
+---+------------+--------------------------+

root
 |-- cid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- leadR: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastSeenDate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstSeenDate: long (nullable = true)
 |-- followRz: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lastseendate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- firstseendate: long (nullable = true)
```

Why does `lastSeenDate` and `firstSeenDate` get changed to all lowercase ( `lastseendate` and `firstseendate`) when using `collect_set`?

Note: My workaround is to go with lowercase ... but why?

Comment: I tested with 2.2 spark version and the names didn't get converted to lowercase. So I suggest you to upgrade spark

Comment: Upgrading Spark is not a workaround option as this runs in the corporate environment with CDH 5.9.2. The workaround is to change my variables to lowercase. The question is why does this happen?